# Error creating beans name with contactService and Injection of autowired dependency failed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

**ERRORS**

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Sep 30 16:01:51 NPT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [datasource-tx-jpa.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.info.ch17.respository.ContactRepository com.info.ch17.service.jpa.ContactServiceImpl.contactRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.info.ch17.respository.ContactRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.info.ch17.respository.ContactRepository com.info.ch17.service.jpa.ContactServiceImpl.contactRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.info.ch17.respository.ContactRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.info.ch17.respository.ContactRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    ... 29 more
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
```

**schema.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CONTACT;
CREATE TABLE CONTACT (
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
, LAST_NAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
, BIRTH_DATE DATE
, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(2000)
, PHOTO BLOB
, VERSION INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
, UNIQUE UQ_CONTACT_1 (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)

);
```

**test-schema.sql**

```
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Clarence', 'Ho', '1980-07-30');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Scott', 'Tiger', '1990-11-02');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('John', 'Smith', '1964-02-28');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Peter', 'Jackson', '1944-1-10');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Jacky', 'Chan', '1955-10-31');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Susan', 'Boyle', '1970-05-06');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Tinner', 'Turner', '1967-04-30');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Lotus', 'Notes', '1990-02-28');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Henry', 'Dickson', '1997-06-30');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Sam', 'Davis', '2001-01-31');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Max', 'Beckham', '2002-02-01');
insert into contact (first_name, last_name, birth_date) values ('Paul', 'Simon', '2002-02-28');
```

****datasource-tx-jpa.xml****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
<jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
<jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
</property>
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.apress.spring3.ch16.domain"/>
<property name="jpaProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">
org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
<context:annotation-config/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.apress.spring3.ch16.repository"
entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Spring MVC Filter  -->
    <filter><filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>ForceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>
    HttpMethodFilter
    </filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>
    Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityMangerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!-- Filter Mapping -->



    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**root context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
<import resource="classpath:datasource-tx-jpa.xml" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.info.ch17.service" />
</beans>
```

**Servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jspx" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.info.ch17.we.controller" />



</beans:beans>
```

**Contact CLASS**

```
package com.info.ch17.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

@Entity
@Table(name="contact")
 public class Contact implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1572699331590746106L;
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int version;
private String description;
private DateTime birthDate;
private byte[] photo;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
@Column(name="LAST_NAME")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
@Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Lob
@Column(name="PHOTO")
public byte[] getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}
public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
@Column(name = "BIRTH_DATE")
@Type(type= "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
public DateTime getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}
public void setBirthDate(DateTime datetime) {
    this.birthDate = datetime;
}
@Version
@Column(name ="VERSION")
public int getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
}
@Transient
public String getBirthDateString(){
    String birthDateString="";
    birthDateString = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd").print(this.birthDate);
    return birthDateString;
}
public String toString() {
    return "Contact - Id: " + id + ", First name: " + firstName
    + ", Last name: " + lastName + ", Birthday: " + birthDate
    + ", Description: " + description;
    }
```

}

**CONTACT RESPOSITORY CLASS**

```
package com.info.ch17.respository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.info.ch17.domain.Contact;

public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact, Long> {
```

}

**Contact Service Class**

```
package com.info.ch17.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.info.ch17.domain.Contact;

public interface ContactService {

public List<Contact> findAll();
public Contact findById(Long id);
public Contact Save(Contact contact);
}
```

**Contact Service Implemenation Class**

```
package com.info.ch17.service.jpa;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.info.ch17.domain.Contact;
import com.info.ch17.respository.ContactRepository;
import com.info.ch17.service.ContactService;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

@Service("contactService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {
@Autowired
private ContactRepository contactRepository;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly= true)
public List<Contact> findAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Lists.newArrayList(contactRepository.findAll());
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Contact findById(Long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return contactRepository.findOne(id);
}

@Override
public Contact Save(Contact contact) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return contactRepository.save(contact);
}
```

}

**Controller Class**

```
package com.info.ch17.web.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.info.ch17.domain.Contact;
import com.info.ch17.service.ContactService;

@RequestMapping("/contacts")
@Controller
public class ContactContoller {
 final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactContoller.class);
 @Autowired
 private ContactService contactService;
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String list(Model uiModel) {
 logger.info("Listing contacts");
 List<Contact> contacts = contactService.findAll();
 uiModel.addAttribute("contacts", contacts);
 logger.info("No. of contacts: " + contacts.size());
 return "contacts/list";
}
}
```

**MavenDependency**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-       instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.info</groupId>
<artifactId>ch17</artifactId>
<name>ch17</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.8.2</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.7</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.160</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last error, it looks like a typo. The relevant part of the stacktrace is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.`OpenEntityMangerInViewFilter`
```

You wrote `OpenEntityMangerInViewFilter` when it should be `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` (Man **a** ger instead of Manger). And the typo exists in your web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Your JPA repositories base package appears to be referencing the wrong package. Change the JPA repository base package from ...ch16... to the correct base package that references the ...ch17... base package

Comment: Edited with a possible suggested solution

Comment: Did you change it to exactly this?  com.info.ch17.respository

Comment: AS your suggestion <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.info.ch17.respository"/>